# How to style the collection_check_boxes elements

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a group of checkboxes via collection_check_boxes in rails.

The problem is they are all end to end on a single line and in bold text.

I would like to know how I can make each element on its own line and not be bold?

Here's my collection:

```
<div> 
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:service_ids, Service.all, :id, :service_type) %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :service_ids, Service.all, :id, :service_type, {:item_wrapper_class => 'my_class_name'} %>
```

With some CSS:

```
.my_class_name {
  ...
}
.my_class_name input {
  ...
}
.my_class_name .collection_check_boxes {
  ...
}
```

Using whatever class name you prefer.

Comment: Thanks!  How do I add a line break after the checkbox?

Comment: You would most likely use CSS to accomplish any formatting. Try `display: block` on each input element.